# JavaScript Date Calculation Show/Hide Div Issue with dates or logic?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to use Javascript to have divs appear between certain dates. There are three divs. I can't figure if I have an error in my logic or an error in the code. I'm trying to teach myself JavaScript by the way so I'm not interested in prepackaged scripts. Thanks in advance for your advice!

JavaScript:

```
<script>
    const date = new Date();
    let offset = 0;
    const threshold = new Date();
    threshold.setMonth(7); //January is 0!
    threshold.setDate(7);
    if (Date.now() > threshold) { 
      offset = 1;
}
var theDate = new Date();
var previous_year = date.getFullYear() - 1 + offset;
var current_year = date.getFullYear() + offset;
var next_year = date.getFullYear() + 1 + offset;

console.log(previous_year);
console.log(current_year);
console.log(next_year);
</script>

<script>
window.setInterval(function(){
  var current = new Date();
  var expiry = new Date("August 01")
  var expiry2 = new Date("February 01")

  if(current.getDate()>=expiry.getDate()){
    $('#one').show();
    $('#two').hide();
    $('#three').hide();
  }

  else if(current.getDate()<=expiry2.getDate()){
     $('#one').hide();   
     $('#two').show();
     $('#three').hide();
   }

  else{
     $('#one').hide();   
     $('#two').hide();
     $('#three').show();
   }
};
$('#one').show(); 
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="one" style="display:none">DIV 1 Show >= August 01</div> 

<div id="two" style="display:none">DIV 2 Show <= February 01</div>

<div id="three" style="display:none">DIV 3 Show if February 02 - July 31 </div>
```

Comment: What is shown, and what do you WANT be shown?

Comment: In your JS, your `setInterval` misses a `)`. In your HTML you should replace `<` and `>` with `&lt;` and `&gt;`.

Comment: To go along with @AlessioCantarella's comment, here's an HTML character code reference: https://www.rapidtables.com/web/html/html-codes.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, you need to change this

```
}; // <-- semi-colon is not expected here.
$('#one').show();
```

to this

```
}) // <-- change to parenthesis.
$('#one').show();
```

Looks like you've got a typo on in there. When I do that, "#one" shows as expected.

Comment: Thank you @Critical Error ... you found my critical error!

Answer (score 0):

1)Don't use setInterval

2)Use https://api.jquery.com/ready/ to wait for dom load ($(function() { }))

3)Why you try hide others when checking one condition (they already hiden)? I prefer 3 simple if's:

```
if (current.getDate() >= expiry.getDate()) {
    $('#one').show();
}

if (current.getDate() <= expiry2.getDate()) {
    $('#two').show();
}

if (current.getDate() > expiry2.getDate() && current.getDate() < expiry.getDate()) {
    $('#three').show();
}
```

I've didn't check logic of comparison but idea is same just make it simple as possible to understand

Comment: Thank you. Makes sense and makes me feel stupid at the same time!